# Find span element based on text written inside li Bs4 scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find the text located in the `<li>`, if it exists I want to scrape the `<span>` text, but if it does not exist I will raise exception, for example:

```
if 'Floor' found then scrape the span
```

[image]

This is my code and it works perfect but scraping everything without any condition :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

# Set base url & headers :
baseurl = 'https://aqarmap.com.eg'
headers = { 
    'User_Agent' : 
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'
    }
test_link = 'https://aqarmap.com.eg/en/listing/3138984-for-rent-cairo-new-cairo-el-narges-el-narges-omarat'
r = requests.get(test_link , headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
title = soup.find('h1').text.replace('\n','')
loc = soup.find('span', {'property':'name'}).find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
sub_loc = soup.find('span', {'property':'name'}).find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
floor = soup.find('span' , class_='badge badge-default').text.replace('\n','')
room = soup.find('span' , class_='badge badge-default').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
baths = soup.find('span' , class_='badge badge-default').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
finish = soup.find('span' , class_='badge badge-default').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
view = soup.find('span' , class_='badge badge-default').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
area = soup.find('span' , class_='badge badge-default').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
date = soup.find('span' , class_='badge badge-default').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
price = soup.find('div' , class_='listing-price-content').find_next('span').text
print(title,loc,sub_loc,floor,room,baths,finish,view,area,date,price)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it would be good to check if the `tag` you are looking for exists before applying the `text` method:

```
title = title.text.strip() if (title := soup.find('h1')) else None
```

To select tag by text and check if it exists, you can go with `css selectors` and `-soup-contains()`:

```
floor = tag.text.strip() if (tag := soup.select_one('ul.list-group li:-soup-contains("Floor") span')) else None
```

---

Above works well for some tags, but to go `generic` and get rid of these confusing property selections, I would suggest the following - Use a `dict` to store the information in a list of dicts. So you are save if you create a dataframe based on it and a propertiy is missing. `Pandas` will fill this outomatically with `nan`.

```
data = {}
data['title'] = soup.find('h1').text.strip()
data['loc'] = soup.find('span', {'property':'name'}).find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
data['sub_loc'] = soup.find('span', {'property':'name'}).find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
data.update(dict([li.stripped_strings for li in soup.select('ul.list-group li')]))
```

**Benefits - You can do adjustments simple, filter if you like and export results in a strucured way.**

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
    
baseurl = 'https://aqarmap.com.eg'
headers = { 
    'User_Agent' : 
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'
    }

data = []

def scrape(test_link):
    r = requests.get(test_link , headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')

    data = {}
    data['title'] = soup.find('h1').text.strip()
    data['loc'] = soup.find('span', {'property':'name'}).find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
    data['sub_loc'] = soup.find('span', {'property':'name'}).find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').text.replace('\n','')
    data.update(dict([li.stripped_strings for li in soup.select('ul.list-group li')]))
    return data

urlList = ['https://aqarmap.com.eg/en/listing/3138984-for-rent-cairo-new-cairo-el-narges-el-narges-omarat',
           'https://aqarmap.com.eg/en/listing/3124476-for-rent-cairo-new-cairo-el-narges-el-narges-omarat?source=related-listing-source']

for url in urlList:
    data.append(scrape(url))

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

| title | loc | sub_loc | Floor | Room | Baths | Finish Type | Size (in meters) | Listing ID | Publish Date | Price | Seller Role | Payment Method | Price Per Meter | View |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Furnished Apartment For rent in El Narges Omarat | El Narges | El Narges Omarat | 3 | 3 | 2 | SUPER_LUX | 180 M² | EG-3138984 | 09/01/2022 | 19,000 EGP | Agent | Cash | 106 EGP/M² | nan |
| Furnished Apartment For rent in El Narges Omarat | El Narges | El Narges Omarat | 2 | 2 | 2 | SUPER_LUX | 180 M² | EG-3124476 | 30/12/2021 | 19,000 EGP | Agent | Cash | 106 EGP/M² | Garden |

Comment: YOU ROCK IT ! really thanks for this SUPER assist. the function helped me a lot and solved the problem. actually i have learned something new today using (.stripped_strings with .update). thanks again DUDE

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following approach useful, particularly an alternative way to extract items from the "bread crumb" list at the top:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


# Set base url & headers :
    
baseurl = 'https://aqarmap.com.eg'
headers = { 
    'User_Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'
}
test_link = 'https://aqarmap.com.eg/en/listing/3138984-for-rent-cairo-new-cairo-el-narges-el-narges-omarat'
r = requests.get(test_link , headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')

# Store all available items in a dictionary
ul_list_group = soup.find('ul', class_='list-group')
data = {}

for li_item in ul_list_group.find_all('li'):
    items = list(li_item.stripped_strings)
    
    if len(items) == 2:
        data[items[0]] = items[1]

req_elements = [
    'Floor', 'Room', 'Baths', 
    'Finish Type', 'Size (in meters)', 'Listing ID', 
    'Publish Date', 'Price', 'Seller Role', 
    'Payment Method', 'Price Per Meter',
    'Swimming pool',     # test case to show missing item
]

# Store all parts of the breadcrump in a list (last 3 required)
ul_breadcrumb = soup.find('ul', class_='breadcrumb')
breadcrumb_data = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in ul_breadcrumb.find_all('li')]

title = breadcrumb_data[-1]
sub_loc = breadcrumb_data[-2]    
loc = breadcrumb_data[-3]
    
# Build a suitable row of data (give missing entries 'N/A')
row = [title, sub_loc, loc] + [data.get(element, 'N/A') for element in req_elements]
print(row)
```

Giving you:

```
['Furnished Apartment For rent in El Narges Omarat', 'El Narges Omarat', 'El Narges', '3', '3', '2', 'SUPER_LUX', '180 M²', 'EG-3138984', '09/01/2022', '19,000 EGP', 'Agent', 'Cash', '106 EGP/M²', 'N/A']
```